# Open CV , video overlay

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to overlay a image on a video, which has rapid camera movement. I am using a green line as a reference point coordinate to overlay. Using segmentation methods i extracted the green line and found the coordinate point on the top of the line to overlay, when it is appearing in the frame.

The problem i am encountering is, when the green line appears blurry (because of the camera movement), the coordinate points changes with 1 or 2 pixel compared to other frames. so in the overlayed output video, the overlayed image looks shakey, because of the coordinate difference.

Can anyone help me with this. I am using opencv c++

Answer (score 1):

You could low pass filter your image movement to get rid of rapid, shaky movements to some extent.

If you have the full video sequence available at once, you can also use the information of future frames for filtering

Comment: @karthik Yes exactly, try the same in the frequency domain